# php method to read only part of remote file

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am working with `file_get_contents` getting remote files and processing them. Unfortunately the files are quite large and I only need a small segment from each. I know exactly from what offset I would need to read and the length of it but reading the php manual it seems that this is possible with `file_get_contents` only on local files.

Is there a method which doesn't download the whole file?

Comment: see http://www.ankur.com/blog/106/php/resume-http-downloads-php-curl-fsockopen/ it's relavent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this a good way to handle it is to use cURL and `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `fopen`, `fseek` and `fread` function instead of `file_get contents`

here are the links to the documentation of

- [fopen](http://am.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
- [fseek](http://am.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php)
- [fread](http://am.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

`fopen` opens the file as a stream of bytes and you can seek into your desired position using `fseek` and read as much byte as you need using `fread`

Comment: fseek will read the data, and discard it on a remote file. No gain here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to open a remote file and move the file pointer to a certain point. You need some kind of remote service that provides that feature for you.

Although fopen and fseek seem to work, there is a cullpit. Form the [manual](http://am.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php):

> Not all streams support seeking. For those that do not support
>   seeking, forward seeking from the current position is accomplished by
>   reading and discarding data; other forms of seeking will fail.

As for implementing a service, there a numerous example. I like the rsync solution, that mirrors only changed blocks from a remote to a local machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the files from an http server you could set the `Range` header if the remove server supports that.